# PHP Execute Python Script on button click

Tags: php, python

I am using php to have a button refresh a python script. The goal of this is to when a certain input is present and a button is pressed, to run the python script. If there is no user input, there is a default value for `$input_val`, just incase. The way I have been trying to test this is in my python file, I have a line that should output to `var/tmp/my_logfile.log`, but no logs are being returned when run through the php page. Like every other stack article I've seen it works in the command prompt.

The code I use to try this has been the following:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
    exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py ".$input_val."');
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="update" method="post" >
    <button name = "update" type="submit"> Update charts </button>
</form>
```

Some of the references I have used, but to no luck:

[Execute Python script from Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811253/execute-python-script-from-php)

[HTML form button to run PHP to execute Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264368/html-form-button-to-run-php-to-execute-python-script)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=105932

https://serverfault.com/questions/679198/executing-a-python-script-through-php-button

Comment: Presumably the Python script fails to run. Check exec() manual page. Use the 2nd and 3rd optional parameters to debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a variable in a single quote string, unless that is what you actually want. Instead, either break out and concatenate, or use double quotes:

```
<?php exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py "' . $input_val . '"'); // note extra single quotes
```

Or:

```
<?php exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py \"$input_val\"");
```

The above codes presume you actually type the double quotes in the terminal.

If not, just get rid of them like so:

```
<?php exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py ' . $input_val );
```

Or:

```
<?php exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py $input_val");
```

Comment: Used the option <?php exec("/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/python_test.py $input_val"); and it logged.

Comment: Glad I could help!